# mysqld_multi error during start

Tags: mysql

hy guys,
i had a problem with mysqld_multi since 2 days.
I had to run fsck because i had a problem with the hard drive after this i encounter this issue.

When i try to start mysqld_multi with verbose i receive this error:

WARNING: mysqld_safe is beign used to start mysql. In this case you may need to pass "ledir=..." under groups [mysqldN] to mysqld_safe in order to find the actual mysqld binary. ledir (library executable directory) should be the path to the wanted mysqld binary.

This is my my.cnf

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin=/usr/bin/mysqladmin
log=/var/log/mysqld_multi.log
user=multi_admin
password=secret

[mysqld1]
port=1111
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1/mysql.pid
socket=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1/mysql.sock
user=mysql
server-id=1111
relay-log=/var/log/mysql1/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin=/var/log/mysql1/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=database1
```

i hope somebody could help me

thanks

Comment: Facing the same issue. Some progress?

Comment: unfortunally no....i had divided the slave istance with multiple server and create a mini backend for monitoring the slave status. i think is some kind of bug.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the mysqld file location.

```
[root@xyz ~]# find / -name mysqld
/usr/libexec/mysqld
[root@xyz ~]#
```

Then you need just to add the following lines to your my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin=/usr/bin/mysqladmin
log=/var/log/mysqld_multi.log
user=multi_admin
password=secret

[mysqld1]
port=1111
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1/mysql.pid
socket=/var/lib/mysql-databases/mysqld1/mysql.sock
user=mysql
server-id=1111
relay-log=/var/log/mysql1/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin=/var/log/mysql1/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=database1
mysqld=mysqld_safe ---> only script name of mysqld_safe
ledir=/usr/libexec --> location of mysqld file
```